# Returning to activity after Twitter OAuth finished

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

I have Twitter OAuth working in my application using an intent-filter in my manifest. How I have implemented it, once the user clicks a button to post via Twitter I start a new Activity (lets just called it TwitterLoginActivity), that new TwitterLoginActivity creates a new Intent with the authUrl like this:

```
Intent oauthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
```

This opens a browser, I authorize my app, and it returns in the `onResume()` function of TwitterLoginActivity. At this point I post to twitter just fine and do a finish() on this activity.

All this works like a champ, but in calling this finish() it returns to the Twitter.com webpage I just authorized from. I'm not great at understanding how the activity stack works, but is there anyway to remove all of the WebViews of Twitter.com that I saw and on that finish() it just returns back to the original point in my application where the user had clicked the post button?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you resolved your issue, but yesterday I had the same problem and I resolved it this way:

1) In the intent to lauch the WebBrowser to sign in on Twitter, add the next flags:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent);
```

2) In the Manifest, where you declare the TwitterLoginActivity that launches the intent, add the property:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

3) When the login with Twitter is completed, WebBrowser finishes and goes back to TwitterLoginActivity but onCreate isn't called because of singleTask launch mode, onNewIntent is called instead. To save the token and token secret, you have to move the code from onResume to OnNewIntent.

Now, if you press the back button or finish TwitterLoginActivity, it goes to the previous activity and the WebBrowser never shows up again.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: render the oauth web page in a WebView you control rather than launching out to the browser app.

The oauth web page, when it calls its callback, will actually be replacing itself in the webview, where your WebViewClient can catch that expected URL, process the results, and finish() the webview (removing it from the activity stack).

In other words, the WebView will be under your direct control, rather than being the browser.

Comment: Could you PLEASE refer to an example?

Comment: @Kondra007 see top 4 hits of https://www.google.com/search?q=android+oauth+webview+example

Comment: This is not correct, because the user won't see the URL that is sent to in a WebView, so the user may be scammed and not notice.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect time to use Activity.startActivityForResult() instead of Activity.startActivity().  You're original activity just needs your TwitterLoginActivity to login the user, so once done, it should return back to your original activity.

Implement onActivityResult() to handle the response from TwitterLoginActivity.

[Read about it here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: Hmm, that could work.  So in the onActivityResult handler how would I bring the UI focus back to that activity?  The activity stack would still be wanting to point at the browser.  Is there some kind of "bring to front" function I can perform on an activity?

Comment: Ya, this doesn't quite work for my purposes.  It seems that two of my TwitterLoginActivities are getting created.  The original one that I created when the button is clicked to start the OAuth process and then one that gets created when the Intent-Filter kicks it off.  So the second one gets killed, but it ends up just returning it to the original which is still showing the Twitter.com screen.